# Is there a way to store custom colors in a file and access them from code in iOS?

Tags: ios

I am an iOS newbie but I have some experience programming for Android. I recall that in Android you could define a set of custom colors in a *colors.xml* file that you could use in your code, and therefore, there was no need to define a new color programmatically each time it had to be applied somewhere.

My question is: does a similar mechanism exist in iOS? I have searched throughout the Internet for a way to create custom colors once in some file and use them programmatically in my iOS app but have found nothing.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As vokilam suggested, it is always good to create a **Category** using `UIColor` and adding your own custom colors through class methods inside the category. It is quite handy and easy to have a track of colors inside a single class. Something like:

In Xcode, File -> New --> New ---> File... Cocoa Touch -> Objective-C Category -> Next -> Select UIColor in "Category on" list --> Give a name for the category --> Next --> Create

This gives you .h and .m file... In your .h file, add a custom color method like

```
+(UIColor *)customLightGreenColor;
```

And in the .m file, you can implement the method something like (You have different options to set your colors here):

```
+(UIColor *)customlightGreenColor
{
    UIColor *lightGreenColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.5 green:0.87 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0];
    return lightGreenColor;
}
```

Likewise, you can add any number of colors in your category and use it in your application. Hope this gives you a heads up...

Comment: Your step-by-step explanation saved me lots of trouble. I followed your instructions and it works! Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad that it worked for you. You can accept the answer if it serves you the purpose..

Answer (score 3):

You can extend UIColor class with [category](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html) and define and implement colors there. Like `[UIColor blackColor]`.

In fact, you can abstract from particular color names and use method names such as `primaryColor`, `secondaryColor`, `defaultTextColor`, `alternativeTextColor`, `inverseTextColor` and so on.

Comment: Thank you for the useful solution. I did not know about Categories in Objective C. It seems that this solution could be applied in a similar fashion to custom fonts, images and so...

Comment: Yes fonts, storyboards. Please, mark the correct answer

Answer (score 3):

Follow these steps to create a resource file in which you'll keep your colors and their values:

**1.** Create and add a `plist` file in your project resources.

**2.** Set type of `plist` as `array`. Add different colors as `array elements`.

**3.** Set `type` of each color (array element) as `dictionary`.

**4.** Add a `string` item in each element to set `color name` of each item.

**5.** Add 3 `float items` as `Red, Green, Blue` for storing RGB `color values`.

---

You can use your color file wherever you want by following code:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *colorsPlistPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Colors.plist"];
NSMutableArray *colors = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:colorsPlistPath]];

//get color and their properties like:
NSDictionary *aColor = [colors objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *colorName = [aColor objectForKey:@"Color_Name"];
float redValue = [aColor floatForKey:@"Red"];
float greenValue = [aColor floatForKey:@"Green"];
float blueValue = [aColor floatForKey:@"Blue"];

UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithRed:redValue/255.0f green:greenValue/255.0f blue:blueValue/255.0f alpha:1.0];
```

If you already know how to create and use plist files as resources, the whole process would be much easier for you.

Comment: Thank you for the response but this approach seems more complex than the Categories solution. I will take it into account for other issues that could be resolved with this alternative method.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  Dozens of posts around this don't give anywhere near as helpful of an answer as this one.  Thank you thank you.  Now to create an Xcode extension.. =)